# Restoring a revoked ios certificate

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I had earlier downloaded my ios distribution certificate.
Recently I mistakenly revoked it.

Is there a way to restore the certificate from this copy that I have? Or do I have to request a new one?

Comment: As far as I know apple doesn't have a interface to restore a certificate that has been revoked and I think it is easy to request a new one ...

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such interface available in apple so its better to create a new certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Revoking a certificate will delete it from your computer **and** Apple developper center. 
There is currently no option in developer center ("Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles") that allows to restore a certificate.

You will have to create a new one.